# To display lists in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to knockout.js and try to build simple list using Google map API and I can only make it work using jquery. Please guide me how to accomplish same task with knockout.js

I use Google places API and display all shopping malls in a map in certain area, I want the name of those shopping malls to display in a list as well.

I accomplish it with jquery using simple function:

```
function ResultsViewModel(list) {
    var location = list.name;
    $('.list').append('<li>'+ location + '</li>');
}
```

However, I need to have the same using knockout binding and I can't figure out how to do that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try a binding called foreach -  .http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html.  If you are stuck, please update the question with more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple Example to construct a list in knockout, kindly refer this

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: location }">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addLocation">Add</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
 ko.applyBindings({
        location: ko.observableArray([ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]),
        addLocation: function() { this.location.push('New item'); }
    });    
</script>
```

Hope it helps.